# How to use python print in Apache nifi?

Tags: python, debugging, apache-nifi

I am new to Apache Nifi and would be interested to use prints in the ExecuteScript processor with Python as script engine.

In order to debug the script step by step I would like to be able to use built-in Python print functions. The only method I found so far is to use `outputStream.write()` but this method is limited because you can only output strings.

Does anyone know a better solution for debugging Python scripts in Apache Nifi?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The `print()` function built in to Python prints to the standard output (i.e. usually the console). In NiFi, this won't work for you. You should use the `log` object that is injected by the framework into your script. This `log` object has multiple functions which allow output at different severity levels (`debug`, `info`, `warn`, `error`, etc.). By default, the `ExecuteScript` processor only writes the messages at `warn` or above, so you can either use `log.warn("my message")` or change the default log level for the processor in `conf/logback.xml`. The output will show up in the `logs/nifi-app.log` file.

Example script (with `existing_attr` set to the current time from a previous processor):

```
flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    log.warn("Running inside the python script: " + flowFile.getAttribute("existing_attr"))
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "modified_from_script", "true")
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Output in `logs/nifi-app.log` (last line is from the script internals):

```
2020-08-04 19:39:51,762 INFO [NiFi Web Server-119] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Starting GenerateFlowFile[id=ba947905-0173-1000-d104-9e557d7a6e94]
2020-08-04 19:39:51,762 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled LogAttribute[id=ba94af15-0173-1000-3f99-5d91aebbeee9] to run with 1 threads
2020-08-04 19:39:51,763 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled GenerateFlowFile[id=ba947905-0173-1000-d104-9e557d7a6e94] to run with 1 threads
2020-08-04 19:39:52,135 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled ExecuteScript[id=bc72b93f-0173-1000-0716-e5b91a545dc5] to run with 1 threads
2020-08-04 19:39:52,139 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript ExecuteScript[id=bc72b93f-0173-1000-0716-e5b91a545dc5] Running inside the python script: 2020-08-04 19:39:51.763 -0700
```

[More info about getting started with scripting in NiFi](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/02/executescript-processor-hello-world.html)